# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select a line in Jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select a single line (current line, where the marker is) in Jupyter lab notebooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I am assuming here** that you need the selected line to be cut, copy, or paste. Jupyter Notebook like vscode will automatically select the entire line, when no text selected.
All you have to do is keep your cursor somewhere on the line and do the usual Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v commands.

This is not very intuitive because the entire line is not highlighted, but it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

With cursor in the line press
Home then Shift+End
or
End then Shift+Home

Comment: Shift+End works great for me, thank you!